# Text to Mesh, Change Back Mode?

Tags: mesh

I Recently made an intro. I separated the text letters and converted to mesh so that I could do [these effects](https://youtu.be/1eZYRE-liPk). Now everyone says I'm unable to go back to editable text mode. Is there an add-on to get back from mesh to text? Or any other way to transfer all key frames to a text object so I could get it back somehow?

Comment: No. There is no way to change mesh back to text.

Comment: *"It's actually stupid that blender haven't fixed this from the start!"* this is what makes this question opinion-based and potentionally unanswerable. *"some really good art could be unavailable to edit back!"* just create a copy prior to converting text to mesh. Or study Animation Nodes addon and create it dynamically